# ¿Cuál es la condición para realizar el producto punto de 2 vectores en 3D o en general de cualquier dimensión en Python con Numpy?

Tags: python, array

```
import numpy as np
arrayejm = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
print(arrayejm)
print()
print("shape=",arrayejm.shape)
print()
print("dimensiones=",arrayejm.ndim)
print()
ex2 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[5,6,7],[7,8,8]]]).reshape((2,1,6))
print(ex2)
print()
print("shape=",ex2.shape)
print()
print("dimensiones=",ex2.ndim)
print()
dot_pro = arrayejm @ ex2
print(dot_pro)
print()
print("shape=",dot_pro .shape)
print()
print("dimensiones=",dot_pro .ndim)
```

Al correr obtengo lo siguiente:

```
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]

shape= (2, 2, 2)

dimensiones= 3

[[[1 2 3 3 4 5]]

 [[5 6 7 7 8 8]]]

shape= (2, 1, 6)

dimensiones= 3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bf3c8c9f1f9b> in <module>()
     15 print("dimensiones=",ex2.ndim)
     16 print()
---> 17 dot_pro = arrayejm @ ex2
     18 print(dot_pro)
     19 print()

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 2)
```

No entiendo que esta mal, el shape del 1er vector es (2, 2, ***2***) y del 2do vector es (***2***, 1, 6); la longitud de la 3era dimension del primer vector es ***2*** y la longitud de la 1era dimension del segundo vector tambien es ***2***; por lo que pienso que el producto punto deberia efectuarse ya que ambas longitudes son iguales; pero no es asi, ante todo esto viene mi pregunta, hay alguna una condicion o requisito para realizar el producto punto de 2 vectores en 3D o en general de cualquier dimension en Python con Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada debemos tener en cuenta que el [producto punto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_escalar) sólo se da entre dos *vectores*,una matriz nxm no puede ser multiplicada escalarmente por otra matriz a no ser que estas sean matrices en la que una de sus *dimensiones* sean 1, es decir: *`un vector`*. Por tanto usted lo que esta realizando es una [multiplicación de matrices.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicaci%C3%B3n_de_matrices) Esto se puede evidenciar al momento que utiliza el operador `@`.

### Condiciones:

Para poder multiplicar dos matrices, la primera debe tener el mismo numero de columnas que filas de la segunda `mxn @ nxk` razon por la cual tiene un error de tipo *ValueError* **sus dimensiones *columna-fila* no son iguales** de ser iguales resultaria una matriz con el mismo número de filas de la primera y con el mismo número de columnas de la segunda: ``mxk`  a continuacón anexo un ejemplo y mas adelante explicare su funcionamiento.

### Ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
 
#inicialización de los arrays
a = np.array([[2, 1], [5, 4]])
b = np.array([[3, 4], [7, 8]])
 
#producto matricial
salida = a @ b
 
print(salida)

[[13 16]
 [43 52]]
```

### ¿Como funciona?

Como podemos observar la matriz resultante seria la multiplicacion de la matriz a con la matriz b matematicamente esto se puede ver como:

```
salida = [[2, 1], [5, 4]] @ [[3, 4], [7, 8]]
       = [[2*3+1*7, 2*4+1*8], [5*3+4*7, 5*4+4*8]] #multiplicacion de las componentes
       = [[13, 16],[43, 52]]
```

Ademas de `@` `numpy` nos proporciona varias maneras de realizar multplicación de matrices para mayor informacion [consulte aquí](https://geekflare.com/es/multiply-matrices-in-python/)